# Calling function without parenthesis

Tags: angular

Hi i'm trying to use `viser-ng` and I need to call a function `onClick` event.

But when I try to use `this` inside my calling function I am getting an error `this is undefined`.

```
<v-chart [forceFit]="forceFit" [height]="height" [data]="data" [onClick]="clickbar"></-chart>
```

In my component

```
clickbar(e: any) {
    console.log('clickbar', e.target); // return clicked data
    console.log("this", this); // return undefined

    this.openDialog(e.data._origin) // error
}

openDialog(data): void {
  console.log(data) // error
}
```

Can you explain me how can I call my `openDialog` function ?

Trying `(click)="clickbar($event)"` but `$event` return `mouseevent` not `clickedData`

Comment: can you explain  "I have an error" or post related error.

Comment: should be using click with angular like `<div (click)="myFunction($event)"></div>`. checkout https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: @jitender I cannot call my function because this is undefined.

Comment: Define `clickbar` as an arrow function: `clickbar = (e: any) => { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component, try to define a variabile containing `this`.

For example

```
public thisRef;


constructor(){
    this.thisRef = this;
}
```

And in the HTML you should be able to do

```
<v-chart [onClick]="clickbar.bind(thisRef)">...
```

This way you're binding the `thisRef`(which is indeed `this`) to `this` inside of your function.

Comment: You're welcome :) In case you needed to pass additional parameters to the function, you can do that inside the `bind` function like this `myFunction.bind(thisRef, param1, param2, ...., paramN)`

Comment: I believe the reason this happens is because this is being passed as a plain javascript function so you lose the context of 'this'. Another way to solve this issue is to define your method like so: clickBar = (e: any): void => {}. Now this is set in the proper context

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using an Input binding "Square Brackets: `[]`" and want to be using the event binding "Round brackets: `()`" like so:

```js
<v-chart [forceFit]="forceFit" [height]="height" [data]="data" (click)="clickbar($event)"></-chart>
```

EDIT:

It looks like there is an `@Input` for the data on the controller and change the signature of the `openDialog`:

In component.ts file

```js
@Input data: any; // This should already exist given the v-chart HTML

openDialog(): void {
  console.log(this.data) // error
}
```

In HTML file

```js
<v-chart [forceFit]="forceFit" [height]="height" [data]="data" (click)="openDialog()"></-chart>
```

Comment: did you notice "Can you explain me how can I calling my openDialog function ?" in op question

Comment: I cannot because `$event` doesn't return my data. `$event` return `mouseEvent`

Comment: @jitender - I did not, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @M.Hol I have made an edit - hopefully this is more inline with the question

Comment: I need use `Square Brackets` because `viser-ng` return `declare type eventFunc = (chart: any, ev: any) => void;`